# How to get comments by instanceId from the COMMENTS table in Activiti 5.22.0?

Tags: alfresco, activiti, alfresco-enterprise

I am trying to get the comments associated with a Process Instance.

I thought these comments were being populated into the `ACT_HI_COMMENT`
table, but they are found in the `COMMENTS` table instead, so
I am not able to get them using `taskService.getProcessInstanceComments`
nor the
`historyService.createProcessInstanceHistoryLogQuery(processInstanceService).includeComments().singleResult()`

Does anyone know which is the correct service call to get this records
in Activiti 5.22.0 / Alfresco APS 1.9.0?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I just found that this can be done by using:

```
com.activiti.service.runtime.CommentService
```

Like this:

```
commentService.getCommentsForProcessInstance(instanceId, true);
```